# What is the exact difference between Charuco Marker and Diamond Marker?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to create an accurate marker tracking device.
And I find charuco marker and diamond marker.

I was able to get a good calibration result through the charuco.

Now, I have to put the 3d model in the right place.
As I studied, I can find about Charco and Diamond. But I can not tell the exact difference between the two. If you know someone, please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make long story short both of them rely on ArUco markers. The only difference is that if Charuco is found in the scene it is assumed to belong to the board and consequently if two identical Charuco markers are found in the scene it causes ambiguity as the system is uable to distinguish between them. On the other hand, Diamond markers are identified based on the relative positions between markers so it is possible to have multiple instances of identical Diamond markers in the scene at the price of much higher computational cost. Please look at this [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d5/d07/tutorial_charuco_diamond_detection.html) for more details.

I recommend you to use different Charuco markers for tracking as its detection is much faster.